# Saving Char from lex to array of Char in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, linux, lex

I'm saving characters from a c file in this array

```
 char *idTable[100];
```

Inside a while loop,

```
if(ntoken == 1){
      idTable[numId] = yytext;
      printf(" \nVariable %s", idTable[numId]);
      printf(" Found\n");
      numId++;
    }
```

and then iterate through the array. The variable yytext is supposed to have only identifiers and variables like `int i, int j, int cont`

When I print those character inside the loop, it shows me the variables that I want to save. But when I iterate the array it takes all the text from the variable to the bottom:

```
while(i<numId){
    printf("%d", i );
    printf("%s", idTable[i]);
    i++;
  }
```

So,

```
printf(" \nVariable %s", idTable[numId]);
      printf(" Found\n");
```

Will print characters like `Variable i Found` But `printf("%s", idTable[i]);` Will always print text inside from the file I want to see. Something like this:

```
i;
  int j;
  char c;
  char cadena;
  float z;
  int 89aa12;
  z=14.9e-8;
  z= 3454y45hrthtrh;
  z== 3454y45hrthtrh;
  z= 3454y45hrthtrh;
  z=12.9;
  cadena="Hola";
  scanf ("%d",i);
  i=i*2;
  printf ("El doble es %d",i);
  Y="Cualquier Cosa 1";
  u=z+y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saving a pointer to the same memory in each element of idTable, so whatever that memory is set to last is what each one will be pointing to.

You need to allocate additional memory for each string you want to save (or use a std::string).

`strdup` may do what you want.

```
idTable[numId] = strdup(yytext);
```

but don't forget to free that memory when you're done with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted. I love you :')

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it's helpful and answers your question :)

Comment: Also, personally, I'd use a std::vector<std::string> and not worry about allocating/de-allocating memory.

Comment: O thanks. I can't upvote since I'm just starting with StackOverFlow and only have 6 reputation.